# Consuming rest API in SSIS 2008

Tags: sql-server, rest, ssis

I am Trying to consume rest API's in SSIS 2008 .
After some research understood that we don not have a native way of consuming rest API's But we could do it using a script task. Does that mean that I need a script/custom code to consume Rest API's ?

Can I do it any language or do we have any specific languages I need to use for coding?

any suggestion regarding this are much appreciated.

My task: I am trying to consume  Rest ApI's of a service to extract into tables  and create reports.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a custom script.

A REST API is just an HTTP call that returns some content. This means that calling a REST API is as simple as making a GET or POST call, eg using WebClient.

Unfortunately, there is *still* no accepted standard to describe REST APIs, which means you can't autogenerate a client from an arbitrary API. Various metadata formats exist, including WASD, exposing XSDs and lately Swagger.

This means that you need to write the proper code to call the API, parse the results and convert them in a tabular format. There *are* some tools that can generate proxy code from Swagger definitions, but I'm not sure if the code can run in .NET 3.5. In any case, you'd have to package the proxy in a library to use inside a Script Task or just copy the generated code inside the Script project.

Transforming the Json or XML response to a tabular format, suitable for use in SSIS or storing in a database, is something that must be hand-coded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.